# Add a checkbox to post screen that adds a class to the title

Tags: posts, custom-field, customization

I'm needing some posts to have different title colors than others, and I figured this would be most conveniently accomplished by some sort of check box on the post creation/edit screen. How would I go about adding the check box, then retrieving the value in the template?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that's right, you need a [Custom Meta Box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) that'll create the checkboxes in the Post Editing screen.

[image: post custom meta box]

In this case, they are radio buttons, as we need only one value.

The following is the code that creates it. Put it in your theme's `functions.php` file or create a [simple plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) so this becomes theme independent.

```
/* Define the custom box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_61041_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_61041_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function wpse_61041_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'wpse_61041_sectionid',
        'Title Color',
        'wpse_61041_inner_custom_box',
        'post',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function wpse_61041_inner_custom_box($post)
{
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( 'wpse_61041_wpse_61041_field_nonce', 'wpse_61041_noncename' );

    // Get saved value, if none exists, "default" is selected
    $saved = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'title_color', true);
    if( !$saved )
        $saved = 'default';

    $fields = array(
        'red'       => __('Red', 'wpse'),
        'green'     => __('Green', 'wpse'),
        'blue'      => __('Blue', 'wpse'),
        'default'   => __('Default', 'wpse'),
    );

    foreach($fields as $key => $label)
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="radio" name="title_color" value="%1$s" id="title_color[%1$s]" %3$s />'.
            '<label for="title_color[%1$s]"> %2$s ' .
            '</label><br>',
            esc_attr($key),
            esc_html($label),
            checked($saved, $key, false)
        );
    }
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function wpse_61041_save_postdata( $post_id ) 
{
      // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
      // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
      if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
          return;

      // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
      // because save_post can be triggered at other times
      if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpse_61041_noncename'], 'wpse_61041_wpse_61041_field_nonce' ) )
          return;

      if ( isset($_POST['title_color']) && $_POST['title_color'] != "" ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'title_color', $_POST['title_color'] );
      } 
}
```

<sup>code based on [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18244/12615)</sup>

#### How to use it in the theme

With the proper CSS rules in place (`h1.default`, `h1.red`, etc), wherever you want to apply the color class to the title (`index.php`, `single.php`, etc), use something like:

```
<?php $title_color = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'title_color', true); ?>
<h1 class="entry-title <?php echo esc_attr($title_color); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

Comment: Good good. You should also look into the [`checked`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) function.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy, aha, that's brilliant, much better! ^\o/^

Comment: One more edit to clean up the callback function a bit. You might want to test it to make sure it still works as expected. Just made so you don't repeat yourself, and more colors can be easily added.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy : Excellent, next round's on me, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

@brasofilo work is great but if you do not want to do much coding, you can do same work from `Custom Fields`. It is hidden by default. You can make is visible from `Screen Options`. Create new field & name it `color` and put color name in `value` field. Then put this code in you theme's `header.php` below `</head>` tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
/*Replace [color-name] with you color example: red*/
#red {color:"red";}
#green {color:"green";}
#[color-name] {color:"[color-name]";}
#[color-name] {color:"[color-name]";}
</style>
    <?php
global $post;
$color = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'color', true);
$id = "id="
?>
```

Then search for `<h1 class="entry-title"` and put this code inside it `<?php echo $id, $color;?>`. Now when evey you want to change title color, choose `color` in custom fields drop down & write color name in `value`.