# How to bring custom meta boxes to custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I had created a custom meta box with the help of [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61041/add-a-checkbox-to-post-screen-that-adds-a-class-to-the-title/72997#72997) but this meta box only appear in Post edit screen. How I can make it visible on "Pages" as well as on custom post types which created by my current theme.

**Update:**
The code is from `function.php` which add Custom Meta Box:

```
    /* Define the custom box */
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_61041_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpse_61041_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function wpse_61041_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'wpse_61041_sectionid',
        'Does this page is in Englsih?',
        'wpse_61041_inner_custom_box',
        'post',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
```

I do not understand how to add `page` & `custom-post-types` to make that `meta-box` visible there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
function wpse_61041_add_custom_box() {
        //Place your custom post types in the array
        $post_types = array ( 'post', 'page', 'another_custom_post_type' );

        //Then loop through all post types and add meta boxes to them
        foreach( $post_types as $post_type )
        {
           add_meta_box( 
             'wpse_61041_sectionid',
             'Does this page is in Englsih?',
             'wpse_61041_inner_custom_box',
             $post_type,
             'side',
             'high'
           );
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, solved by adding         

`$post_types = array ( 'post', 'page' );`

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the add_meta_box() function, wee see that it takes the following structure:

```
<?php
   add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, $context, $priority, $callback_args );
?>
```

Based on the tutorial you linked, "post" is the post type, which is why the box only shows up there. Perhaps you will find it less troublesome to generate your meta box content with ACF then export the PHP to your theme?

[The manual solution is here](http://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/add-meta-box-to-multiple-post-types) (amabil's solution).

Comment: Thanks, but code add meta-box in different way & I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Meta Box API, it is very easy:

- [Meta Box - DeluxeBlogTips.com](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/)

Multiple post meta example:

- [Register Multiple Meta Boxes](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/register-multiple-meta-boxes/)